# Calculating volume of IDW raster below Height of Plane, but it is failing

Tags: arcgis-desktop, area, kriging, inverse-distance-weighted, volume

I am using ArcMap.

I am trying to calculate the volume of water using IDW Tool. When I reach a point to calculate, the statistics below height of plane cannot run, giving me 0.00,

What could be the problem?

[image]